People going through a tough job interview
I have seen a movie on youtube, and I do not remember its name anymore. It was an interview for a job and the paper was blank. If they were mistaking they failed the interview. They have tried to find the question by using different lights and by trying to make each other to fail the interview. At the end one guy shoot another one and the one girl has given the right anwer and wins the interview. I really need the name of it, please help me.

Sounds like the 2009 thriller Exam.

Eight candidates interview for a job and take an exam that has very strict rules; those who break them are disqualified. The forms turn out to be blank, they try using the lights to reveal the answer, one of them shoots the other and in the end, a woman (nicknamed Blonde) figures it out and gets the job. Here's the trailer.
